# Upstart server killed using -9 or -15 but child processes are still alive

Tags: service, process, daemon, upstart, gnu-parallel

Upstart service is responsible for creating a gearman workers which run in parallel as number of cpus with the help of ***gnu-parallel***. To understand the problem you can read my *stackoverflow* post which describes how to run workers in parallel.

> [Fork processes indefinetly using gnu-parallel which catch individual exit errors and respawn](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45127927/3615504)

**Upstart service:** workon.conf

```
# workon

description "worker load"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn

script
  exec seq 1000000 | parallel -N0 --joblog out.log ./worker
end script
```

Oright. so above service is started

```
$ sudo service workon start
workon start/running, process 4620
```

`4620` is the process id of service workon.

4 workers will be spawned as per cpu cores. for example.

```
___________________
Name   |  PID
worker    1011
worker    1012
worker    1013
worker    1014
perl      1000
```

perl is the process which is running ***gnu-parallel***.
And, ***gnu-parallel*** is responsible for running parallel worker processes.

Now, the problem is.
If I kill the workon service.

```
$ sudo kill 4620
```

The service has instruction to re-spawn if killed so it restarts. But, the processes created by the service are not killed. Which means it creates a new set of processes. Now we have 2 perl and 8 workers.

---

```
Name   |  PID
worker    1011
worker    1012
worker    1013
worker    1014
worker    2011
worker    2012
worker    2013
worker    2014
perl      1000
perl      2000
```

If you ask me, the old process which abandon by service, are they zombies?
Well, the answer is no. They are alive cuz I tested them. Everytime the service dies it creates a new set.

Well, this is one problem. Another problem is with the ***gnu-parallel***.
Lets say I started the service as fresh. Service is running good.
I ran this command to kill the ***gnu-parallel***, i.e. perl

```
$ sudo kill 1000
```

This doesn't kill the workers,and they again left without any parent. But, the workon service intercept the death of perl and respawn a new set of workers. This time we have 1 perl and 8 workers. All 8 workers are alive. 4 of them with parent and 4 are orphan.

Now, how do I solve this problem? I want kill all processes created by the service whenever it crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was able to solve this issue by [post-stop](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#post-stop). It is an event listener I believe which executes after a service ends. In my case, if I run `kill -9 -pid-` (pid of the service), post-stop block is executed after the service process is killed. So, I can write the necessary code to remove all the processes spawned by the service.

**here is my code using post-stop.**

```
post-stop script
    exec killall php & killall perl
end script
```